# Diagonal split of 2 images with transition

Tags: html, css

I was wondering if it was possible to split a screen into 2 parts diagonally as shown on the picture. Once I'd hover over Picture A, the diagonal line would shift a bit to the right, revealing more of picture A while hiding a bit of picture B (I'm thinking transition?), and when I'd hover over picture B the opposite would happen.

[image: Picture of how I imagine the split]

Thanks in advance,
Martin

Comment: What have you tried already to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The diagonal image transition effect is unique request. I tried my best, Can you please check revealing effect.

```css
section {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  width: 400px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.diagonalHover {
  position: absolute;
  width: 66%;
  height: 200px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
.diagonalHover.first,
.diagonalHover.second {
  background-image: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/07/20/22/33/vajdahunyadvar-1531470_960_720.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
.diagonalHover.second {
  background-image: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/02/05/22/17/vendetta-4822543__340.jpg);
}
.diagonalHover.first:hover {
  width: 75%;
  z-index: 1;
}
.diagonalHover.second:hover {
  width: 75%;
  z-index: 1;
}
.diagonalHover.first:hover + .second {
}
.diagonalHover.first {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0%, 50% 100%, 0% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0%, 50% 100%, 0% 100%);
}

.diagonalHover.second {
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="diagonalHover first">
    
  </div>
  <div class="diagonalHover second">
    
  </div>
</section>
```